# android pie emulator not getting downloaded

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using ubuntu 18.04. On the latest android studio I am trying to install android pie emulator. After the downloading finishes I am getting this message [image]

I first installed the emulator for oreo and it got installed without any problems but pie is giving problems. What can be the possible reason and how do I get rid of this. I am running java 11

Edit: I am adding the log. I went to help section and then to 'show log in files' option and there I found many folders each containing a single file in it. I am giving the content of the latest file. Here is the screenshot of the folder I went to

[image]

I am giving the content of the last folder in this.

The log file is very big so please go this link

https://github.com/nikcodes/nikcodes.github.io/blob/master/log.txt

Comment: Could you show us what's in the log? (P.S. If you can't find the log, click on the `Help` menu item > `Show log in explorer`)

Comment: I have updated with the output

Comment: Which file did you upload to your GitHub Page?

Comment: https://github.com/nikcodes/nikcodes.github.io/blob/master/log.txt

Comment: This is the complete log file I got as you directed me

Comment: What happened. Is that not what you are asking for

Comment: I meant as in which file did you upload from that screenshot of a folder?

Comment: The folder just before the idea.log file as seen in the screenshot. In that folder I found the file and and the content on the github page is of that file only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong. First I updated the android studio which had a update for the android emulator. Later I changed the device to pixel 2. Earlier I was using nexus. Maybe that device doesn't support pie. Even oreo was getting downloaded. The only problem was with pie. Finally it has gotten working